# Exact Claim Count for each rows using pivot with join in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

By executing the below SQL 2012 Query, I got the following output

```
declare
    @ticketstatus nvarchar(20) = 'To Be Allocated'

SELECT m1.ClaimSource, m1.Insurance, n1.[Claim Count], n1.[Claim Value],
ISNULL(m1.[0-30],0) [0-30],
ISNULL(m1.[31-60],0) [31-60],
ISNULL(m1.[61-90],0) [61-90],
ISNULL(m1.[91-120],0) [91-120],
ISNULL(m1.[121-210],0) [121-210],
ISNULL(m1.[210++],0) [210++]
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ClaimSource, Insurance, CurrentBalance _Count, AgeBucket
    FROM ClaimMaster
) m
PIVOT (
    COUNT(_Count)
    FOR AgeBucket IN ([0-30],[31-60],[61-90],[91-120],[121-210],[210++])
) n
) m1
join 

(SELECT  Insurance, COUNT(Insurance) [Claim Count], SUM(CurrentBalance) [Claim Value] FROM  ClaimMaster 
    WHERE (TicketStatus = @ticketstatus OR @ticketstatus IS NULL)
    GROUP BY Insurance) n1

ON m1.Insurance = n1.Insurance
ORDER BY n1.[Claim Count] DESC
```

How can I get the correct output for Claim Count, Claim Value on the 4, 5 & 6 rows. Instead of showing full claim count, it should show the respective claim count filter by Claim Source such as Claim Count should be 2 and appropriate Claim Value.

Can anyone help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add claimsource and join on that as well?

```
  declare
        @ticketstatus nvarchar(20) = 'To Be Allocated'

    SELECT m1.ClaimSource, m1.Insurance, n1.[Claim Count], n1.[Claim Value],
    ISNULL(m1.[0-30],0) [0-30],
    ISNULL(m1.[31-60],0) [31-60],
    ISNULL(m1.[61-90],0) [61-90],
    ISNULL(m1.[91-120],0) [91-120],
    ISNULL(m1.[121-210],0) [121-210],
    ISNULL(m1.[210++],0) [210++]
    FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT ClaimSource, Insurance, CurrentBalance _Count, AgeBucket
        FROM ClaimMaster
    ) m
    PIVOT (
        COUNT(_Count)
        FOR AgeBucket IN ([0-30],[31-60],[61-90],[91-120],[121-210],[210++])
    ) n
    ) m1
    join 

    (SELECT  ClaimSource, Insurance, COUNT(Insurance) [Claim Count], SUM(CurrentBalance) [Claim Value] FROM  ClaimMaster 
        WHERE (TicketStatus = @ticketstatus OR @ticketstatus IS NULL)
        GROUP BY ClaimSource, Insurance) n1

    ON m1.Insurance = n1.Insurance and m1.ClaimSource = n1.ClaimSource
    ORDER BY n1.[Claim Count] DESC
```

Comment: Wow! Great. Marked as Answered. I already added the ClaimSource & tried but missed to add in the "ON" condition. Now understood, thanks.